# Async method that does not make async calls

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I need to create a method that will connect to my Azure SQL database and read some data. All the methods that call this method are async methods but I don't think I can make the `ReadStateProvinceListAsync` an `async` one.

What's the right approach in these situations? Just ignore the "warning" from the compiler that I have an `async` method that does not use the `await` keyword **or** make the `ReadStateProvinceListAsync` method a regular synchronous method in which case the `GetStateProvinceListAsync` method will give me the same warning.

I want to do it right -- by the book. That's why I want to learn the right approach.

```
public static async Task<List<StateProvince>> GetStateProvinceListAsync(string countryId)
{
   // Check to see if I already have this data cached
   if(gotData)
   {
      // Life is good! Get data from cache.
   }
   else
   {
      // Don't have the data cached. Call the DB read method
      statesList = await ReadStateProvinceListAsync(countryId)
   }
}

private static async Task<List<StateProvince>> ReadStateProvinceListAsync(string countryId)
{
   // Call Azure SQL Database to read data. No async code here!
}
```

Comment: What behavior do you want? Why are you making the method `async` in the first place if you don't `await` anything? After all, that's the reason for making a method `async`: to allow `await`. If there's no asynchronous implementation in `ReadStateProvinceListAsync()`, then don't make it `async` (and take `Async` off the name)

Comment: return await Task.Run(Func<>...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's absolutely no value in marking a synchronous method with the `async` keyword. If your method doesn't make any asynchronous calls make it synchronous:

```
public static List<StateProvince> GetStateProvinceListAsync(string countryId)
{
   // Check to see if I already have this data cached
   if(gotData)
   {
      // Life is good! Get data from cache.
   }
   else
   {
      // Don't have the data cached. Call the DB read method
      statesList = ReadStateProvinceList(countryId)
   }
}

private static List<StateProvince> ReadStateProvinceList(string countryId)
{
   // Call Azure SQL Database to read data. No async code here!
}
```

If for some reason you **must** return a task (e.g. it's an interface or abstract implementation) use `Task.FromResult` to return a `Task` synchronously:

```
private static Task<List<StateProvince>> ReadStateProvinceListAsync(string countryId)
{
    return Task.FromResult(ReadStateProvinceList());
}
```